# How to show default today date and future date disable in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Trying to show default today date and future date disable but not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/zw2vp9q6/

```
  $("#mydate").datepicker("setDate" , new Date());
  $("#mydate").datepicker({maxDate: 0});
```

Comment: Sorry i don't understand. I tried the jsfiddle. When i go to choose a date. I can choose today or any date in the paste.   Do you mean that you want todays date to show in the input box before clicking to select a date.

Comment: I want to show default today date and disable future dates.

Comment: It do it, today is default date and next days is disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#mydate").datepicker({maxDate: 0});
$("#mydate").datepicker("setDate" , new Date());
```

You need to initalise the date picker first by calling `datepicker()` with or with options, in your case there is one option maxDate. Then you can use methods like setDate.